# ModelIt is Undefined [IE7!]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm having problems with a featured content area breaking the site in IE7 which is causing the splash to display above the content (as its also jquery).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/3/design/js/featurebar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
   jQuery( function(){ ModelIt.FeatureBar.init() } );
    //-->
</script>
```

ModelIt is defined inside featurebar.js

Every other browser, the above works fine, in ie7 I get ModelIt is undefined...Any ideas of a work around?

Here is a test page: http://www.prowler.tv/scripts/test.php - I get object unexpected in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (!ModelIt)
```

to

```
if (!window['ModelIt'])
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Didnt help, but I just noticed it says line 38. Line 38 of the JS is :
}).mouseleave(function(){ 
which doesnt make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Don't pay attention to IE6 or 7 error messages.  You can use "try/catch" blocks to narrow down the code that's actually causing the error.

Comment: Updated the first post, its defined properly in the js file but for some reason ie7 doesnt keep it?

Comment: Well that doesn't make much sense. You should post more of the code that supposedly defines the global variable, and the code where the error occurs.